# R: Getting a string from entire dataframe based on pattern

Tags: r, string, dataframe, get

Assuming I have a dataframe containing these details:

```
Name   Card1    Card2
A      A11234   A24321
B      B11234   B24321
C      C11234   C24321
D      D11234   D24321
E      E11234   E24321
```

I would like to extract the strings from this dataframe based on pattern "1234" & "4321" in character form. Assuming I extracted the strings to a variable named *all_cards*, the desired outcome would look like:

```
> all_cards
 [1] "A11234"           "A24321"            "B11234"          "B24321"        
 [5] "C11234"           "C24321"            "D11234"          "D24321"     
 [9] "E11234"           "E24321"        

> str(all_cards)
 chr [1:10] "A11234" "A24321" "B11234" "B24321" ...
```

Please advise, thank you in advance!

Comment: As given, `all_cards` and `str(all_cards)` don't match. Why does `all_cards` only have 3 elements? Are these `list` elements? `str(all_cards)` suggests a `character` vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unlist` the dataframe and use `grep`.

```
all_cards <- unname(grep('1234|4321', unlist(df), value = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `t` which transposes the data frame (excluding `name` column) and coerces it to matrix simultaneously. Finally coerce it to `as.vector`.

```
as.vector(t(dat[-1]))
# [1] "A11234" "A24321" "B11234" "B24321" "C11234" "C24321" "D11234" "D24321" "E11234"
# [10] "E24321"
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Card1 = c("A11234", 
"B11234", "C11234", "D11234", "E11234"), Card2 = c("A24321", 
"B24321", "C24321", "D24321", "E24321")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")
```